# Making footnote marks in beamer use the surrounding color

Tags: beamer, color, footnotes

As is probably well known, footnote marks in beamer are colored using the `footnote mark` beamer-color, which seems to default to black, so that footnote marks are black even when the surrounding text has a different color. Example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
  \color{red}some text\footnote{test} and some more text

  \color{green}some text\footnote{test} and some more text
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image: example slide]

What would be the cleanest way to change this so that footnote marks take on the color of the surrounding text? In this case I'd like the <sup>1</sup> in the main text to be red and the <sup>2</sup> in the next line to be blue, but without explicitly having to write those colors. The <sup>1</sup> and <sup>2</sup> in the footnotes themselves should likewise take on the color of footnote text, which in this case is black.

In particular, I'm *not* looking for this:

```
  {\setbeamercolor{footnote mark}{fg=red}
   \color{red}some text\footnote{test} and some more text
  }
```

because that would also change the color of the mark in the footnote, and also because I have situations in which it's not so easy to figure out what color the surrounding text actually is.

Undefining the color as suggested in [this other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71352/beamer-undefined-color-local-structure), with

```
  \setbeamercolor{footnote mark}{use=,parent=,fg=,bg=}
```

doesn't work either.

What's the cleanest way to make this happen?

An ideal solution would make footnote marks take on the surrounding text color by default but still respect `\setbeamercolor{footnote mark}{...}` if I set it explicitly. But for my current project, it will be acceptable if setting the `footnote mark` beamer-color has no effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Colour setting to `.` takes exactly this into effect:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\setbeamercolor{footnote mark}{fg=.}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \color{red}some text\footnote{test} and some more text

  \color{green}some text\footnote{test} and some more text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This is discussed in section **2.6.3 Using the current color** (p 23) of the [`xcolor` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf).